# Can´t populate table with video frame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, video

Whenever i insert a video it appears a black frame instead of a frame from the video.
The js function "handleFiles" validates if the file inserted is a video. Then creates a video element that after is loaded takes a snap from the video after 10s using canvas. Then with that snap attach the image to the table along with the name of the file

```js
var Video = ['m4v', 'avi','mpg','mp4', 'webm', 'mov', 'mxf'];  
var NameFile = [];

function handleFiles() {
"use strict";
var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
var fileList = inputElement.files; /* now you can work with the file list */

 for(var k = 0; k < fileList.length; k++){ 
 NameFile.push(fileList[k].name);
  }
for( var j=0; j<100; j++){
 
for(var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++){

 // VIDEOS
  
 if(fileList[i].type === "video/"+Video[j]){  
      
 var video = document.createElement('video');
      var timeupdate = function() {
        if (snapImage()) {
          video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
          video.pause();
        }
      };
      video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
        if (snapImage()) {
          video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
        }
      });
      var snapImage = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var image = canvas.toDataURL();
        var success = image.length > 100000;
        if (success) {
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = image;
          document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(img);
        }
        return success;
      };
      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
      video.preload = 'metadata';
      video.src=(window.URL.createObjectURL(fileList[i]).replace('blob:',''));
      // Load video in Safari / IE11
      video.muted = true;
      video.playsInline = true;
      video.play();
  
  // Table for Videos
  for( var lV=0; lV<100; lV++ ){  
   // if for name
  if(fileList[i].name===NameFile[lV]){ 
       
 var Vx = document.createElement("Table");
    Vx.setAttribute("id", "galeriaV" + (i));
    document.body.appendChild(Vx);
 
// imagens of videos 
    var VImg = document.createElement("tr");
    VImg.setAttribute("id", "VTr" +(i));
    document.getElementById("galeriaV" +(i)).appendChild(VImg);

    var ImgV = document.createElement("td");
    var imagV =document.createElement("img");
   
   imagV.src = snapImage;
      imagV.height = 50;
      imagV.with = 50; 
   
    imagV.setAttribute("id", "imageID" +(i));
    imagV.setAttribute("className", "bordered");
 imagV.setAttribute("src","http://placehold.it/200/200/pink/black");
    imagV.setAttribute("onclick","imgClick(this)"); 

    ImgV.appendChild(imagV);
    document.getElementById("VTr" + (i)).appendChild(ImgV);

// files names
    var yV = document.createElement("tr");
    yV.setAttribute("id", "VNTr" + (i));
    document.getElementById("galeriaV" +(i)).appendChild(yV);

    var Vz = document.createElement("td");
    var Vt = document.createTextNode(NameFile[lV]);
    Vz.appendChild(Vt);
    document.getElementById("VNTr" + (i)).appendChild(Vz);
}// fim if name
  } 
    }  
    }
    }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="../JS/galeria.js"> </script>
   <script src="../JS/XML.js"> </script>
    <title>Preview images</title>
    <style>
  input{
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   width:100%; 
  }
  
  table{
   margin-top: 10px;
            border: 0px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
        }

        table.tr{
         width: 50px;
         height: 50px;
        }

        img.bordered{
  border: 3px solid green;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
<h2>Upload images ...</h2>
<input type="file" id="input" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">

</body>
</html>
```

The snippet gives an error at the img Click function is not defined but thats not the problem

Comment: Could you try writing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Maybe you'll solve the problem on your own while writing it? If you're still having problems after writing an mcve, den feel free to post it to stack overflow and we will do our very best to help out :)

Comment: Just edit the question, but still appears a black square instead of a frame from the video element